# How do I not duplicate the div from bootstrap datepicker that it generates

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a standard bootstrap datepicker in a bootstrap modal dialog. I create a new modal every time as the content is dynamic, but there is a datepicker every time. Everything works fine. However, I am starting to notice that every time i launch the modal, bootstrap appends it's UI div to the DOM.  After a while, I have plenty of this at the end of my DOM:

```
<div class="bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget dropdown-menu">...</div>
```

I have other datepickers on the page so deleting all divs with that class is not feasible.

Is there anyway that I can add an id to that div?  any way to distinguish it from the others?

OR,  is this even a problem?  There is basic security so the session times out after 30 min and the user needs to refresh.  So at most 5 hours before lunch and they need to reload, which solves the problem.

how much of a performance hit am i taking with say 200 of these in the DOM?